# AngularJS | Called function doesn't do anything..no errors

Tags: angularjs

Console shows "Function ran, Service ran" when I click it however no http put is fired off... Looks identical to working code I have in production...Nothing complains in my browser console. The other functions are working fine. IE the login function.

Any thoughts?

Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="signup" ng-submit="submitSignupForm()">
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app').controller('Signup', function ($scope, $location, AuthService, vcRecaptchaService) {

$scope.submitSignupForm = function() {

    console.log('Ran function');

    $scope.signupForm.loading = true;

    var email = $scope.signupForm.email.toLowerCase();
    var password = $scope.signupForm.password;
    var company = $scope.signupForm.company;
    var name = $scope.signupForm.name;
    var reCaptcha = vcRecaptchaService.getResponse(newWidgetId);

    AuthService.signup(email, password, company, name, reCaptcha)
    .then(function onSuccess(res){
      $location.path('/dashboard');
    })
    .finally(function eitherWay(res) {
      $scope.signupForm.loading = false;
    });
  };
}:
```

**AuthService.js:**

```
angular.module('app').factory('AuthService', function ($http, $auth, ResponseService, $localStorage, $q) {

return {

signup: function (email, password, name, company, reCaptcha) {
console.log('Service ran')
  return $http.put('/api/user/signupWithEmail', {
      email     : email,
      password  : password,
      company   : company,
      name      : name,
      reCaptcha : reCaptcha
    })
    .then(function onSuccess (res){
      $localStorage.userHash = res.data.user;
      $auth.setToken(res.data.token);
    })
    .catch(function onError(res) {
      ResponseService.error(res);
      return $q.reject();
    });
}
};
```

Comment: I am not sure but `then/catch` part in the service method should be inside the controller function. Because you are returning the promise to the controller.

Comment: It is inside the controller function  isn't it? Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: The code looks fine to me. You must have some exception thrown between your console.log() call and the actual call to the service. Check your console, and use the debugger to execute the lines of code one by one to see what happens.

Comment: Are you saying you don't see the PUT request in your browser's *Network* console?

Comment: @Phil - Yes. Nor is it being received on the api console configured to console.log any incoming requests.

Comment: I don't understand how the request could not appear in he browser network panel, unless you chose to hide XHR requests from the console, or you somehow configured an alternative $http service of an $http interceptor in the app that would prevent the request from being sent. What does `res` contain when you debug your first `then()` callback? Do you have any $http interceptor?

Comment: Try to see if reCaptcha is undefined. Looks like Authservice is ran before reCaptcha resolves.

Comment: @Phil - Yes. My API does actually receive the request :/

Comment: Nothing in browser console though. Other functions like login do have the XHR request.

Comment: I'm looking into the API controller now.

Comment: @gyc per the API console, reCaptcha is resolved correctly.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you did a `console.log(reCaptcha)` in the signup function of AuthService and it's not undefined?

Comment: wth - Thank you for looking at it. There were issues in my API controller. I didn't even look at that because my chrome console did NOT show the put request which lead me to believe the issue was on the front end :/ I'm sorry to waste everyone's time. I would love to know why a misconfigured API controller somehow prevented the chrome console from seeing the put request.